# Is it ok to mark as duplicate & also write an answer to the same question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Is it right for a user to mark a question duplicate & also answer the same question?

Reference Question : [Does the fclose() function in C append the EOF character by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37092016/2142994)

The question was marked as duplicate & also answered by a user.

Well the question is not actually a duplicate, but the answers happen to be same for both.